# Compressing a sentence in python

Tags: python-3.x

so i have this task for school and it states:

develop a program that identifies individual words in a sentence, stores these in a list and replaces each word with the position of that word in the list. The sentence has to inputted by the user of the program.

The example we have to use is:
ask not what your country can do for you ask what you can do for your country
should become:

1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,1,3,9,6,7,8,4,5

I have no idea how to even go about starting this task

Comment: If you haven't even tried anything yet, SO isn't the site to ask this on. Questions that are on-topic include previous attempts, and what went wrong.

Comment: Having said that, you would break the sentence into words, and iterate over the words. If the word has already been seen, replace it with the position in the list. If it hasn't been seen, add it to the list, then replace the word with the position. Also note that while the instructions say to replace it with the position in the list, the example output actually replaces it with the position of the list + 1, since list indices start at 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like that:

```
sentence = input().split(' ')

word_list = []


for i, word in enumerate(sentence, start=1):
    if word not in word_list:
        word_list.append(word)

        to_print = str(len(word_list) - 1)

    else:
        to_print = str(word_list.index(word))


    print(to_print, end=',') if i < len(sentence) else print(to_print, end='')
```